# Webpack does not compress the files enough

Tags: javascript, webpack

this is my webpack config that I use for development and production modes;

```
let debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
import webpack from "webpack";
import LiveReloadPlugin from "webpack-livereload-plugin";
import WebpackNotifierPlugin from "webpack-notifier";
import validate from "webpack-validator";
import failPlugin from "webpack-fail-plugin";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

let loaders = [
    {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts', exclude: /(node_modules)/},
    {
        test   : /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader : 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
        query  : {
            presets       : ['es2015'],
            cacheDirectory: true
        }
    },
    {
        test  : /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
    },
    {
        test   : /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            "postcss-loader",
            "sass-loader?outputStyle=compressed"
        ]
    }
];

let globaljQuery = {
    $              : 'jquery',
    jQuery         : 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
};


let devPlugins = [
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({excludeWarnings: true}),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(globaljQuery),
    new LiveReloadPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    // new ExtractTextPlugin('css/app.css', {allChunks: true}),
    failPlugin,
];

let prodPlugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress : {warnings: false},
        output   : {comments: false},
        sourceMap: false
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(globaljQuery)
];

module.exports = validate({
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: 'eval',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
        alias     : {jquery: __dirname + '/resources/assets/js/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'}
    },
    entry  : [
        // 'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        // 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081',
        __dirname + '/resources/assets/js/main.js'
    ],
    output : {
        path      : __dirname + '/public',
        publicPath: '/public/',
        filename  : 'js/app.js'
    },
    plugins: debug ? devPlugins : prodPlugins,
    module : {
        loaders: loaders,
    },
    postcss: () => {
        return [autoprefixer]
    }
});
```

But for some reason if I minify modules individually it compiles to a smaller bundle than if I delegate the same task to webpack in production mode.

For example if I use uncompressed "owl carousel" plugin and delegate compressing task to webpack the bundle is 43 kb larger.

Plugins such as photoswipe make the bundle around 82kb larger.

jQuery is about 120kb larger...

What do I miss that compressing individual plugins manually is more efficient, as from my point of view the webpack should be doing this task automatically and compressing files to same level as doing it manually...?

Comment: new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    })
why you have this in devplugin, not in prod?

Comment: Yep my mistake. Too much working, I fixed the problem. It was due to devtools. When you work 10-11 hours a day 6-7 days a week you brain plays jokes with you.